# Count down timer reset bug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a count down timer in Unity but the timer is working wrong. The recipeTemplate prefab in the DeliveryManagerUI code spawns every specified time and inside this recipeTemplate is the DeliveryManagerSingleUI code. Each time it spawns, it causes all previous recipeTemplates to reset their timers. What I want is for each one to have its own timer. How can I solve this?

[Timer Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltox3.jpg)

[When the timer ends and when the order arrives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGaEY.jpg)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DeliveryManagerUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    [SerializeField] private Transform container;
    [SerializeField] private Transform recipeTemplate;

    private void Awake() {
        recipeTemplate.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Start() {
        DeliveryManager.Instance.OnRecipeSpawned += DeliveryManager_OnRecipeSpawned;
        DeliveryManager.Instance.OnRecipeCompeted += DeliveryManager_OnRecipeCompleted;

        UptadeVisual();
    }

    private void DeliveryManager_OnRecipeSpawned(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        UptadeVisual();
    }

    private void DeliveryManager_OnRecipeCompleted(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        UptadeVisual();
    }

    private void UptadeVisual() {
        foreach (Transform child in container) {
            if (child == recipeTemplate) continue;
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }

        foreach (RecipeSO recipeSO in DeliveryManager.Instance.GetWaitingWave1RecipeSOList()) {
            Transform recipeTransform = Instantiate(recipeTemplate, container);
            recipeTransform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            recipeTransform.GetComponent<DeliveryManagerSingleUI>().SetRecipeSO(recipeSO);
        }
    }

}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DeliveryManagerSingleUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI recipeNameText;
    [SerializeField] private Transform iconContainer;
    [SerializeField] private Transform iconTemplate;
    [SerializeField] private Slider timerSlider;

    private float timerDuration = 10f;
    private float timer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        iconTemplate.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        timer = timerDuration;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        UpdateTimer();
    }

    public void SetRecipeSO(RecipeSO recipeSO)
    {
        // Set recipe name
        recipeNameText.text = recipeSO.recipeName;

        // Destroy existing icons
        foreach (Transform child in iconContainer)
        {
            if (child == iconTemplate) continue;
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }

        // Instantiate and display icons based on recipeSO
        foreach (KitchenObjectSO kitchenObjectSO in recipeSO.kitchenObjectSOList)
        {
            Transform iconTransform = Instantiate(iconTemplate, iconContainer);
            iconTransform.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            iconTransform.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = kitchenObjectSO.sprite;
        }

        // Reset and start the timer
        timer = timerDuration;
        timerSlider.value = 1f;
    }

    private void UpdateTimer()
    {
        if (timer > 0)
        {
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;
            timerSlider.value = timer / timerDuration;
        }
        else
        {
            // Timer reached zero, handle completion logic here
            // For example, you can disable the timer UI elements or trigger another event.
        }
    }
}
```

In general, I tried a lot of things. I also asked ChatGPT for help, but I didn't get a good result.

Comment: Im guessing it looks like they do but arent because the timer slider isnt different per recipie?

Comment: What do you mean by "previous recipe template to reset thier timers" you only have one bit of timer code here, and your snippet implies it's inside a singleton....

Comment: I think we might need more context of your project